# Doing spring boot logout without POST

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, oauth

I was referring to [this](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/) spring boot oauth guide. For logout functionality, the guide says:

> Spring security's `/logout` endpoint requires us to POST to it.

However I just added a react material UI button with href to `/logout` end point:

```
 <IconButton aria-label="logout" href="http://localhost:8080/logout" >
     <LogoutIcon sx={{color:"white"}}/>
 </IconButton>
```

and it started to work as desired (redirecting to login page on logout since I configured `HttpSecurity.logoutSuccessUrl` and redirect to google login if I try to hit any endpoint directly post logout).

Do I need to implement async POST request to `/logout` link using axios or am just fine with current implementation?

Answer (score 0):

According to this article ['Should Logging Out Be a GET or POST?'](https://www.baeldung.com/logout-get-vs-post#:%7E:text=If%20we%20expose%20our%20logout%20as%20a%20GET%20request%20and%20present%20it%20as%20a%20link%2C%20these%20processes%20may%20inadvertently%20log%20users%20out%20while%20trying%20to%20prefetch%20links%20on%20the%20page.), if we expose our logout as a GET request and present it as a link, browsers may inadvertently log users out while prefetching links on the page.

The HTTP spec also states that GET methods should only be used to return content, and should not have side-effects. (Stating that the user cannot be held responsible for any side-effects of a GET request.)

It would appear the most correct is to perform logout by a PUT or POST request, to clearly indicate an effectful request. For traditional HTTP multi-page applications and for many SPAs, the simplest approach is a synchronous HTTP page navigation by form post; likely answering a redirect back to the login page.

The assumption here is that for most SPAs, it's rather simpler to have login/ logout outside of the SPA; and only enter the SPA once the user is authorized.

(Commenters have suggested to prefer PUT to POST in regards of API design, since the request semantically is *updating* session state rather than *creating* information. However I haven't checked whether this works with Spring Security myself.)

If you have an SPA and really need it to include the 'logged out' state (most don't), logout could possibly be an AJAX post, then updating top-level application state to a 'logged-out' state.

Comment: I mostly agree, but, when I can choose, prefer a  PUT (update user state) than a POST (which should mean create something)

Comment: @ch4mp Good point -- I've added your suggestion to the answer.